# Google Places API returns Swedish-sounding map keys

Tags: json, api

The documentation for Google Places notes that latitude and longitude information will be returned with keys of "lat" and "long."  I haven't seen that to be the case: a few days ago I was getting responses with "Ia" and "Ja" as keys.  I shrugged and changed my code to access the data through those keys.  Now I'm getting responses with "Ja" and "Ka" as keys.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

(Yes, I checked, I've got "language=en" in the request string)

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.  The first conclusion is that I am an imbecile.  But here's the second:

First, this particular call was actually to the Maps Geocoder, which returns lat/lng data in the form of a google Lat/Lng object.  This object labels its fields oddly and inconsistently(like above), but provides accessor methods in the form of lat() and lng().

Go thou and do better than I did.